# Redux-saga Module augumentation for select effect

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I want that the select effect to return my state type. I'm using module augumentation for this as such

```
import { SelectEffect, Tail } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { IReduxState } from 'reducers/rootReducer';

declare module 'redux-saga/effects' {
    export function select<Fn extends (state: IReduxState, ...args: any[]) => any>(
        selector: Fn,
        ...args: Tail<Parameters<Fn>>
    ): SelectEffect
}
```

The problem is that when I try to select my piece of state, that state is not typed as expected

```
const users = yield select((state) => (state.users));
```

here **users** has type **any**

[image]

[image]

How should I properly type this effect?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Typescript still doesn't have support for mapping/type inference of injected values based on the yielded expression.

There was some discussion around this in ~2015:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2983
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2873

However the [result](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2873#issuecomment-98012010) was to provide only better support for common iterators  and return types (and not async runners like redux-saga) in TS 3.6 and there hasn't been done anything else since then. Note that the better return type support was leveraged in redux-saga [here](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/1892), though that isn't helpful for your case.

There has been some [disccusion](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/issues/970) around this in the saga repo itself, where it was discovered that you can actually get around this with a hacky solution using the `yield*` syntax. Someone actually went ahead and added this solution on top of redux saga here:
https://github.com/agiledigital/typed-redux-saga

It seems to be working for most cases, though there are some issues with multiple different types when using the `all` effect etc.

There is even a PR in redux-saga to support the same thing in redux-saga itself, but it hasn't moved forward since the maintainer of redux-saga is busy with other things:

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/2053

So the only solutions right now are:

- a) Keep using redux-saga and add an explicit type for variables to which you assign injected stuff from yield expressions:

```js
const value: Stuff = yield select(getStuff);
```

- b) Use typed-redux-saga

(or of course you can just ignore types in these cases)

Answer (score 1):

Since `state` is well-typed (its type is `IReduxState`), and there's a compiler error under `state.users`, I'd say that the problem is that `IReduxState` interface does not have `users` property.